# javascript - Replace an object with another one

Tags: javascript

```
var obj1 = New MyObject('Object 1');
var obj2 = New MyObject('Object 2');

var foo = { anObject : obj1 };

foo.anObject = obj2;
console.log(obj1.name);
```

Naturally, `obj1` didn't changed. But how to replace `obj1` by `obj2` in the whole script assuming I can only access `foo` ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Your code + use `foo.anObject` instead of `obj1` when referencing it.

Comment: What for do you want to replace it "*in the whole script*"?

Comment: @BillyMoon @Bergi 
I'd just like a pointer. In C, it should be `foo.anObject = &obj1` and then `*(foo.anObject) = obj2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove all properties in obj1 and then add all properties from obj2. But note that obj1 wont hold the reference to the same object as obj2 but make a new cloned one. Also note the below is shallow cloning with `a` as target:

```
var replaceObject = function(a, b) {
    var prop;

    for ( prop in a ) delete a[prop];
    for ( prop in b ) a[prop] = b[prop]; 
};

var a = {a: 1},
    b = {b: 2};

replaceObject(a, b);

a // {b: 2};
// but:
a === b // false
```

Comment: It's not really the ideal solution, but it's not the ideal case eather. +1 for a simple and clean solution

Comment: It works for what I do now, but isn't there a cleaner solution ?

Comment: Should the loop body in line 5 be 'a[prop] = b[prop];'?